# linux + understanding Chrony logs and conclusions from logs

Tags: linux, redhat, ntp, time

we are using chrony service in order to sync linux clients to NTP server in our cluster

since we get diff time between machines
we enable the chrony logs to understand the reasons that machines in the cluster are with diff time

example of chrony logs

```
[root@server_2 chrony]# ls 
 tracking.log
 statistics.log
 measurements.log


    [root@server_2 chrony]#

    more  tracking.log

    ==================================================================================================
       Date (UTC) Time     IP Address   St   Freq ppm   Skew ppm     Offset L Co  Offset sd Rem. corr.
    ==================================================================================================
    2019-11-02 16:28:29 193.34.2.90      7      3.319      0.413 -3.194e-05 N  1  7.595e-06 -2.451e-08
    2019-11-02 16:29:33 193.34.2.90      7      3.280      0.241 -4.739e-06 N  1  7.793e-06 -8.506e-09
    2019-11-02 16:30:38 193.34.2.90      7      3.280      0.162  9.378e-07 N  1  7.708e-06  2.806e-06
    2019-11-02 16:31:42 193.34.2.90      7      3.279      0.194 -8.777e-05 N  1  2.454e-05  1.565e-06
    2019-11-02 16:32:47 193.34.2.90      7      3.276      0.265 -6.126e-05 N  1  1.462e-05 -5.085e-08
    2019-11-02 16:33:52 193.34.2.90      7      3.205      0.589 -4.021e-05 N  1  1.390e-05 -6.203e-08
    2019-11-02 16:34:56 193.34.2.90      7      2.670      0.777 -4.523e-05 N  1  9.487e-06 -2.635e-09
    2019-11-02 16:38:10 193.34.2.90      7      2.547      0.381 -2.507e-05 N  1  1.595e-05 -3.263e-08
    2019-11-02 16:39:14 193.34.2.90      7      2.369      0.398 -8.562e-05 N  1  1.637e-05  1.624e-05
    2019-11-02 16:40:20 193.34.2.90      7      2.323      0.264 -8.542e-06 N  1  1.498e-05 -9.931e-08
    2019-11-02 16:41:25 193.34.2.90      7      2.331      0.240  7.737e-06 N  1  1.872e-05  5.261e-06
    2019-11-02 16:42:30 193.34.2.90      7      2.338      0.211  3.433e-06 N  1  1.958e-05 -2.259e-06
    2019-11-02 16:44:40 193.34.2.90      7      2.309      0.395 -1.485e-04 N  1  4.641e-05 -3.489e-06
    2019-11-02 16:45:44 193.34.2.90      7      2.200      0.760  3.455e-07 N  1  4.970e-05 -1.446e-07
    2019-11-02 16:46:50 193.34.2.90      7      2.193      0.951 -3.363e-04 N  1  8.643e-05 -4.877e-07
    2019-11-02 16:47:54 193.34.2.90      7      2.183      1.243 -4.516e-04 N  1  1.033e-04 -2.225e-07
    2019-11-02 16:48:59 193.34.2.90      7     -0.736      5.314 -5.285e-04 N  1  6.903e-06 -3.506e-07
    2019-11-02 16:50:04 193.34.2.90      7     -4.855      0.933 -2.600e-04 N  1  5.356e-06 -5.370e-07

..

     more measurements.log
        ========================================================================================================================
           Date (UTC) Time     IP Address   L St 123 567 ABCD  LP RP Score    Offset  Peer del. Peer disp.  Root del. Root disp.
        ========================================================================================================================
        2019-11-02 16:41:25 193.34.2.90     N  6 111 111 1111   6  6 0.48 -1.000e-04  5.220e-04  1.477e-06  5.206e-01  6.248e-01
        2019-11-02 16:42:30 193.34.2.90     N  6 111 111 1111   6  6 0.62 -1.400e-05  4.490e-04  1.477e-06  5.206e-01  6.258e-01
        2019-11-02 16:43:35 193.34.2.90     N  6 111 111 1101   6  6 0.72  7.440e-04  1.466e-03  1.477e-06  5.206e-01  6.268e-01
        2019-11-02 16:44:40 193.34.2.90     N  6 111 111 1111   6  6 0.00  1.770e-04  2.860e-04  1.477e-06  5.206e-01  6.278e-01
        2019-11-02 16:45:44 193.34.2.90     N  6 111 111 1111   6  6 0.03 -7.100e-05  5.100e-04  1.478e-06  5.206e-01  6.287e-01
        2019-11-02 16:46:50 193.34.2.90     N  6 111 111 1111   6  6 0.00  3.820e-04  2.460e-04  1.477e-06  5.206e-01  6.174e-01
        2019-11-02 16:47:54 193.34.2.90     N  6 111 111 1111   6  6 0.00  5.190e-04  2.260e-04  1.484e-06  5.206e-01  6.183e-01
        2019-11-02 16:48:59 193.34.2.90     N  6 111 111 1111   6  6 0.00  5.240e-04  2.450e-04  1.488e-06  5.206e-01  6.193e-01
```

regarding the logs above

what is the important values in the logs that indicate about problem ?

how to know if Crhony service sync meet the standard?

```
chronyc -n sources
210 Number of sources = 1
MS Name/IP address         Stratum Poll Reach LastRx Last sample
===============================================================================
^* 193.34.2.90                   6   8   377    97    +20us[  +27us] +/- 1079ms
[root@master02 ~]# chronyc -n tracking
Reference ID    : 193.34.2.90 (193.34.2.90)
Stratum         : 7
Ref time (UTC)  : Sat Nov  2 21:26:29 2019
System time     : 6144.669921875 seconds fast of NTP time
Last offset     : +0.000007461 seconds
RMS offset      : 15.415832520 seconds
Frequency       : 32.717 ppm slow
Residual freq   : +0.002 ppm
Skew            : 0.029 ppm
Root delay      : 0.521056 seconds
Root dispersion : 0.796153 seconds
Update interval : 141.3 seconds
Leap status     : Normal
```

Comment: Please include your configuration and the output of `chronyc -n sources` and `chronyc -n tracking`.  See https://serverfault.com/q/951179 for general advice about monitoring NTP.

Comment: see please the updates

Comment: please give your opinion about the sanity

Comment: You still haven't shown your configuration.